# Open one drop-down, close another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am using this script to open a drop down menu and then close it when anything else but the trigger is clicked. Now I am trying to add a second drop down to another area on the page and repeat the script but it is breaking.

For instance, I click button A (Gravatar), and drop down A opens.

However when I add the second script and click button B (category) to open drop down B, down down A stays open.

Also adding the second script breaks the drop down close function of the first script.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
  function openAccount(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("gravatar").classList.toggle("open");
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("gravatar").classList.remove("open");
  }
</script>
<script>
  function openCategory(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("category").classList.toggle("open");
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("gravatar").classList.remove("open");
  }
</script>

<li class="gravatar">
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn" onclick="openAccount(event)">
    <img src="<?php echo $gravatar; ?>" alt="" />
    <span class="fa fa-icon fa-caret-down"></span>
    </a>
  <ul class="dropdown" id="gravatar">
    <li class="header">
      <?php echo $user['email']; ?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<div class="category">
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn" onclick="openCategory(event)">Properties<span class="fa fa-icon fa-caret-down"></span></a>
  <div id="category">Test</div>
</div>
```

Goals:

- Multiple drop down menus on different parts of the page.
- On click opens drop down.
- Click on anywhere else on the page closes the drop down.
- On click also closes any previously opened menu.

Comment: paste your html as no where you are calling those two functions and also your are not using JQuery

Comment: The HTML is a bit complicated and page is password protected...I'll do my best...

Comment: Just need a basic html structure ...not the full html .... as in [mcve]

Comment: Also please try to indent your code for readability

Comment: added the applicable html.

Comment: You should associate the A to the UL it opens more generically so that you can add as many As and ULs as you like without having to change the script. Maybe use a data attribute on the A that contains the related UL id. Also, instead of an A, use a span styled like an A if that's the look you want.

Comment: I appreciate the advise however I have not idea how to accomplish what you are saying. Can you provide a code snippet based on the sample provided above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something really simple like putting a data* attribute on the element that's clicked on that contains the ID of the element to show or hide, e.g.

```js
// Toggle hidden class on/off
function toggleVis(event) {
  // Stop click on element bubbling (to body)
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Get target element
  var el = document.getElementById(this.dataset.id);
  // If non-target elements are visible, hide them
  hideAll(el);
  // Toggle target
  el.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
// Hide all, excluding passed element
function hideAll(el) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul:not(.hidden)')).forEach(function(node){
    if (el != node) node.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}

// Attach listeners
window.onload = function() {
  // Add to linkLike spans
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.linkLike')).forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', toggleVis, false);
  });
  // Add hideAll listener to wndow
  window.addEventListener('click', hideAll, false);
  // Run hideAll
  hideAll();
}
```

```css
/* style span like link */
.linkLike {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* class to hide element */
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul id="a"><li>A</ul>
<ul id="b"><li>B</ul>
<ul id="c"><li>C</ul>
<ul id="d"><li>D</ul>

<div><span class="linkLike" data-id="a">Toggle A</span></div>
<div><span class="linkLike" data-id="b">Toggle B</span></div>
<div><span class="linkLike" data-id="c">Toggle C</span></div>
<div><span class="linkLike" data-id="d">Toggle D</span></div>
```

Of course there are other ways to do the association, but ID is simple, explicit and doesn't depend on document layout or formatting.

Comment: I am testing your snippet however, it does not seem to satisfy my goals of being able to click A to open A, being able to close A by clicking anywhere else on the page, and being able to close A when clicking B, assuming A was already open when B was clicked.

Comment: @user1447958—add a function to "hideAll" and hide all visible ULs that you want to hide (maybe `ul:not(.hidden)` and add the .hidden class). Add a click listener to the body to run it, and also call it from the *toggleVis* function.

Comment: I really do appreciate these suggestions. Unfortunately everything you mention is way over my head. If you can provide some code that would be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You are over complicating things and really should should attempt a solution before asking for help. But since I started down this track…

Comment: This is a tremendous effort. It seems to be working good so far with one minor exception which I cannot seem to figure out how to get around. Been at it for about two hours.

My code contains a nested ul li ul, the child ul is the dropdown being revealed, so the ul:not(.hidden) selector also hides my parent ul. What other kind of selector can a put there that will not select any ul's that have no class set at all?

Comment: An easy solution is to add a class called "hideable" (or similar) to the ULs that can be hidden, then you can use a rule like `'ul.hideable:not(.hidden)'`  to exclude any UL that doesn't have the "hideable" class (actually, in that case you can remove "UL" from the selector so: `'.hideable:not(.hidden)'`, which is also quite semantic and can apply to any type of element, not just ULs). ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot and this helped solve a major pain point.